# Visual Studio 2013 and Workflow Xaml files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Since installing VS 2013 and Update 4 I've tried opening a XAML file.

I get the waiting for an operation to complete box forever (like 20 min) then it kills it and reloads the solution.
While its going on my cpu is pegged at 50%

Anyone else experienced this?

This is blocking me from working .. I have to keep going back to VS 2012 to get it to load.

Comment: Gonna wager this is an issue with your machine.  Reinstall VS.

Comment: I have already.  That was the first thing thought of by others around me as well.  Funny thing is right after re-installing I had an issue with Office 2010.  Had to reinstall that then Outlook worked.  But I wonder If I'm running into a problem with Microsoft.dll's .  sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting Visual Studio's settings through the Visual Studio command prompt with the following command:

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

Its recommended you export your existing IDE settings via the Tools | Import/Export Settings option before running the above though so you'll at least retain your key bindings (if you customize them).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks will try and let you know.

Comment: Yeah If I run the command devenv /resetsettings for VS 2013.  It's doing the same thing it does for my XAML open "waiting for operation" and hangs for 15 - 20 minutes, gives an error window with DEBUG and close Program.  When I hit DEBUG it finally came up with OutofMemoryException, but that's because if I watch memory it's slowly creeping up from 2GB to 5GB and.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe deleting the 'obj' folder from your project directory will fix the solution? VS caches stuff in their and it may have gotten corrupt in some way. You'll need to close Visual Studio before you attempt this. It will NOT impact your source code at all.

Comment: It could be your Windows registry needs some cleaning. A tool like CCleaner can be used to look for issues in your registry.

Comment: Seems to be something to do with Office Incompatibility in my opinion.  I installed VS 2013 on a machine that doesn't have either on it and it's working fine.